# Playwright : How to continue test execution after assertion failed?

Tags: typescript, playwright, playwright-typescript

I need to run multiple links on a single test. The test scenarios are almost the same for the 4 links, but will have different color or data.

I have tried this, but once link A has failed, it will fail link B,C and D (It will fail the whole test). Is there a way to run those 4 links independently from each other?

```
test("Validate pages", async () => {
    const browser = await chromium.launch({headless: false});
    const context = await browser.newContext();
    const page = await context.newPage()

const urls = ["linkA", "linkB", "linkC", "linkD"]
  for (let i = 0; i < urls.length; i++) {
     const url = urls[i];
     await page.goto(`${url}`); 

// insert test code here that needs to run on the 4 links.
}
}
```

Answer (score 4):

#### [Use soft Assertions](https://playwright.dev/docs/test-assertions#soft-assertions). It will continue test even after one assertion failed.

> **soft assertions do not terminate test execution immediately but mark the test as
> failed to report in results later along with all test steps results.**

You can do that in single test.Inside loop just verify the expected URL:

```
for (const url of urls) {
  await page.goto(`${url}`)
  await expect.soft(page).toHaveURL(/.*PageA/)
}
```

Further Reading:

https://timdeschryver.dev/blog/improve-your-test-experience-with-playwright-soft-assertions

https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/soft-asserts-better-way-test-your-code-serhat-u%C3%A7ar

Answer (score 0):

One Approach : You can use dotenv / Crossenv for this, set the links into environment env files  based on the environment. then using Interpolation construct the dynamic path to the dotenv config. so on every run u call different link based on environment and execute ur testcase.